# mysql subquery as if condition ( only if needed )

Tags: mysql, if-statement, full-text-search, case

I want to perform a textsearch on a table containing posts belonging to topics within groups. Depending on the privacysettings for these groups I need to run a subquery to check if the requesting user is a member of the groups containg search matches.

Databasescheme:

```
Table: posts
Columns: id, group_id, title, text

Table: groups
Columns: group_id, privacy

Table: group_memberships
Columns: group_id, is_member
```

The privacy column in the group table contains an integervalue.

```
1 = public, anyone can access the data    
2 = system, anyone can access the data
3 = private, only members can access the data
```

What the query should do:

```
1. Find some matches in the post table
2. Check the group privacy in the groups table -> a value HIGHER THAN 2 requires a membership check
3. Do a membership check on the group_memberships table if required
```

I really don't know how do handle this.

It looks like mysql supports two ways? IF statements and case expressions?

What would be a correct way for this?

PS: The subquery for membership checking should be optional and only firing if needed.

Something "like" this..
Pseudocode:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.text
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN groups g
ON g.group_id = p.group_id
AND p.title is not null
WHERE EXISTS(
CASE
WHEN g.privacy < 2 THEN ''everything is ok. Nothing more needed''
ELSE (''Membership check needed'')
END
)
```

EDIT:
Can someone confirm that this is a/the right way?

```
SELECT p.id, p.channel_id, p.title, g.name
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN user_groups g
ON g.id = p.channel_id
AND p.title is not null
WHERE g.privacy < 2 OR (SELECT count(*) FROM user_groups_memberships WHERE uid = 1 AND channel_id = p.channel_id AND rank IS NOT NULL AND is_banned IS NULL) = 1
GROUP BY p.parent_id
```

Comment: I will try to answer this when I get to my workstation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this might not be the best answer, but this solves the above problem without using IF or CASE expressions.

```
select 
   p.id,
   p.group_id,
   p.title,
   p.text
from
   posts p,
   groups g

where 
   p.group_id = g.group_id 
   and
   ( 
     g.privacy<3 
     or 
     ( g.privacy => 3 and 
          (select is_member from group_memberships gm where gm.group_id = g.group_id) = 1)
   );
```

Assuming here that `is_member = 1` means that id is a member and `0` means that id isn't.

Comment: Hi. This way the group_membership table will get queried every time. Even if it isn't needed. I'm searching for a way which queries the membership table only in cases where privacy > 2. Added some "pseudocode to the question" @ngoa

Comment: @user2429266 Please post the results of how much time it is taking compared to the using other expressions once you have the other solution. It would be very insightful in knowing that.

Comment: Now... I don't have any other queries to compare with except some like the one from you. But accessing three tables 100% of the time vs (two tables with a third one in 50% of the cases) should be noticeable I guess.

Comment: @user2429266 see if the modified query would do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76682/discussion-between-ngoa-and-user2429266).